# Nativescript Cloud Build for Android Circle CI

Tags: android, cloud, nativescript, circleci, circleci-2.0

I am trying to create a circle ci build job for sample nativescript application. The job can be found at https://circleci.com/gh/rakeshgirase/CloudBuild/3. It fails with error **You are missing the nativescript-cloud extension and you will not be able to execute cloud builds**. Can someone please guide me how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add following to your config.yml file. It will basically select the choices asked by these plugins.

```
  - run: echo yes | tns setup
  - run: echo yes | tns cloud setup
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to run the tns cloud setup command which would install the nativescript cloud extension.
https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/docs-cli/cloud/cloud-setup

If nativescript cloud extension is installed for circle ci you need to perform the steps mentioned here.
https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/nativescript-4-not-working-on-circleci/6363

Comment: Thanks @Baskar. I added it but no luck. See the updated failure at https://circleci.com/gh/rakeshgirase/CloudBuild/4

Comment: @Rakesh as suggested follow the steps in discourse portal

Comment: Hi @Baskar. The build instructions are for macOs which is paid on circleci. So I want to set this up on Linux.